# I want to check the user already exist or not using user data (mobile number) in fire base android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check the user already exist or not using users mobile number

Here is my code

```
  private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {




                       DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                       ref.child("users").child(mobile).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {


                            @Override
                          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                               if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                    // use "username" already exists

                                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "already account there",
                                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                               } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "account not exist",
                                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                               }
                           }

                            @Override
                           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                           }
                        });



                         // FirebaseUser userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    //    String uid = userid.getUid();




                     //   mDatabase = mDatabase.child("Users");
                     //   Map<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();

                     //  userData.put("Number", mobile);
                     //   userData.put("Password", "mypassword");
                      //  userData.put("Confirmed", "not confiremed");
                      //  userData.put("Email", "jaisonkerala1@gmail.com");


                     //  mDatabase = mDatabase.child(mobile).child(uid);
                    //    mDatabase.setValue(userData);



                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "login success",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "login faild",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                       // Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OTP was wrong",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

screenshot of database

[image]

I want to check the database if the user exist or not by comparing "number" node in database and the users list or with the data. Now its giving the toast user not exist if I use the same mobile number

Comment: It's `ref.child("Users")` and not `ref.child("users")`.

Comment: rest of the code is proper?

Comment: Yes, looks good to me.